# How can I convert a Unix timestamp back to time?

Tags: php, time, unix-timestamp

I have the following Unix timestamps.

> 1301982430 1301982430 1301981474
>
> 1301981466 1301981466 1301981066
>
> 1301981058 1301981058 1301980388
>
> 1301980373 1301980373 1301979082
>
> 1301978478 1301978478 1301978478

How do I convert it back to time that's human friendly?

This doesn't seem to work,

```
strtotime($item->timestamp);
```

Comment: "This doesn't seem to work" --- just curious, have you even tried to read documentation before you use a function that you don't know how it works?

Comment: [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) does the exact opposite of what you want to do "Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp"

Comment: Oops. I found it from a blog, i should have referred to the official manual.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use the php date function to get the date and time.

```
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s',$item->timestamp);
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [`date()`](http://php.net/date) or [`strftime`](http://php.net/strftime).

```
echo strftime("%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S", time());
echo date('Y-m-d, H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

```
date($format, $timestamp)
```

As stated:

> Returns a string formatted according
>   to the given format string using the
>   given integer timestamp or the current
>   time if no timestamp is given. In
>   other words, timestamp is optional and
>   defaults to the value of time().

Some format examples:

```
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
$today = date("m.d.y");                         // 03.10.01
$today = date("j, n, Y");                       // 10, 3, 2001
$today = date("Ymd");                           // 20010310
$today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');     // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6 Satpm01
$today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');   // it is the 10th day.
$today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");               // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
$today = date('H:m:s \m \i\s\ \m\o\n\t\h');     // 17:03:18 m is month
$today = date("H:i:s");                         // 17:16:18
```

Answer (score 5):

[date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

```
echo date(DATE_ATOM, '1301980373');
```

Answer (score 3):

## Make use of the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-timestamp-set.php) Class.

---

```
   <?php
    $dt = new DateTime();
    $dt->setTimestamp(160000); //<--- Pass a UNIX TimeStamp
    echo $dt->format('H:i'); //"prints" 20:26
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$item->timestamp);
```

Is perhaps better, because the hour has to be capital!

Comment: Please read http://php.net/date quickly - it's literally preference, H is 24 hour time, h is 12hour time.