# How to create DateTime from a Unix timestamp with milliseconds?

Tags: php, php-7

How to create `DateTime` from a Unix timestamp with milliseconds?

Such as `1612119630095`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547953/how-can-i-convert-a-unix-timestamp-back-to-time

Comment: @StefanAvramovic it's without millis.